# Как сделать поисковик среди элементов?

Tags: java, javafx

Есть VBox, в котором есть десятки Label элементов, как мне сделать поиск среди них?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вызвав метод:

```
ObservableList<Node> javafx.scene.layout.Pane.getChildren()
```

Вы получите обект коллекции [ObservableList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) ну а в нем провести поиск уже тривиальная задача. Можете так или иначе перебрать коллекцию или воспользоваться штатным методом поиска по индексу(Если он известен)...

Comment: Спасибо, думал тоже просто все дочерние элементы перебрать, но надеялся, что уже есть инструмент :)

Comment: @jessez мой вам совет используйте стрим если коллекция действительно не маленькая и параллельте его при необходимости